# How to invoke a method of a superclass using the same method name in a subclass

Tags: java

I'm kind of confused on overriding a method in the super class. Can anyone help me on solving this problem that is bolded? I'm not exactly sure how to invoke the method 'say' in the main method of "basketball."

A basket ball team has 12 players. Each player is one of 3 types - center, guard, forward.

A team has 4 centers, 4 forwards, and 4 guards.

Each player has a unique name and a unique number.

Define a base class Player. A Player class has a name member, a string, and a number member, an integer.

Derive a Center class, a Guard class and Forward class from the Player class.

Define appropriate constructors, accessors and mutators for the base class and derived classes.

Define a base class method, Say. Says displays the player's name and number

**Override the base class Say method in the derived classes.
The derived classes' Says display the player's position and invoke the base class Say.
Together, the base class Say and the derived class Says display a player's name, number, and type**

```
public class Player
{
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected int num;

    public Player(String first, String last, int jerseyNum)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        num = jerseyNum;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first)
    {
        firstName = first;

    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last)
    {
        lastName = last;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setNum(int jerseyNum)
    {
        num = jerseyNum;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }

    public void say()
    {
        System.out.printf("The player's name is %s %s and his jersey number is %d.\n", firstName, lastName, num);

    }
}

public class Center extends Player
{
    private String center;

    public Center(String first, String last, int num, String position)
    {
        super(first, last, num);
        center = position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position)
    {
        center = position;
    }

    public String getPosition()
    {
        return center;
    }

    @Override
    public void say()
    {
        System.out.printf("This player plays the %s position", center);
    }
}


public class Forward extends Player
{
    private String forward;

    public Forward(String first, String last, int num, String position)
    {
        super(first, last, num);
        forward = position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position)
    {
        forward = position;
    }

    public String getPosition()
    {
        return forward;
    }

    @Override
    public void say()
    {
        System.out.printf("This player plays the %s position", forward);
    }
}   



public class Guard extends Player
{
    private String guard;

    public Guard(String first, String last, int num, String position)
    {
        super(first, last, num);
        guard = position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position)
    {
        guard = position;
    }

    public String getPosition()
    {
        return guard;
    }

    @Override
    public void say()
    {
        System.out.printf("This player plays the %s position", guard);
    }
}
public class basketball
{
    public static void main(String[] Args)
    {
        //Player bballPlayer =  new Player("Jon", "Jones", 25);
        Center positionCenter = new Center("Jon", "Jones", 25, "Center");

        positionCenter.say();
    }
}
```

Comment: call it using like `super.mehtodName()`.

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code? How does this differ from what you want?

Comment: If you look over on the right of this very page, under the word titled 'Related', there are lots and lots of answered questions that might give you everything you need to know! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call a super classes method using `super.` as shown in the example shown below:

```
@Override
public void say() {
    super.say();
    System.out.printf(" This player plays the %s position", guard);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to call the super method in the Player class, by doing something like this:

```
@Override
public void say()
{
    super.say();
    System.out.printf("This player plays the %s position", center);
}
```